# How do I comment out a block of code in Stan?

Tags: syntax, comments, stan

This feels like a duplicate question, but I can't find it anywhere here or elsewhere!

So, in R, you can comment out a block of code with `Ctrl + Shift + C`/`Cmd + Shift + C`. Does anyone know how to perform the equivalent action in Stan? All I know is that Stan uses `//` in place of R's `#`. I've tried `Ctrl + Shift + /`/`Cmd + Shift + /`, to no avail.

Thanks so much for any help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a comment within your Stan code by using the following:

```
/* this is a comment block
as opposed to a single
line block */
```

Please see, https://mc-stan.org/docs/2_18/reference-manual/bracketed-comments.html